# Windows 10 / Screen capture fails frequently

Tags: windows-10, clipboard, screenshot

Up to date Windows 10 O/S... screen capture fails sporadically.  Failure rate is between 10% and 90%.

The *failure mode* is that the clipboard will not show anything was captured with the *copy* operation.  Nothing will be in the *buffer* to paste and no new entry will appear in the *Clipboard History*.

It will correctly capture and fail randomly during a single session (between reboots).

I have

- (x3) monitors.  Fails on each of them.
- Fails in all applications (Windows desktop, browser, ...)
- Used the Clipboard history and the issue appears to be that the *copy* does not copy (not that the paste cannot paste)
- Issues are with every form of screen capture inc.: Snip & Sketch and even Adobe Acrobat *take a snapshot*

Comment: Do you have a dedicated GPU, and are your graphics drivers up-to-date? What does "fail" mean? Does it give you an error message, or does it just crash when you try to take a snip, or maybe take the snip, but the snip is blank? Does the Print Screen key on the keyboard work?

Comment: @SamForbis - no error.  no snip is pastable.  no new snip is added to the Clipboard history.

Comment: Have you made sure that "Auto copy to clipboard" is enabled in Snip & Sketch?

Comment: Yep!  It was already enabled - @SamForbis

Comment: When it fails, PrintScreen does nothing - @SamForbis

Comment: Could it be that this is an issue with the clipboard in general as opposed to an issue with just screen capturing? Are you able to say, copy an image from the internet to your clipboard, and then paste it?

Answer (score 0):

First, Window Clipboard History uses a buffer (virtual memory, i.e. *pagefile.sys*). If that buffer fills, it could be causing the issue. Images may be many megabytes, so are particular;y pernicious. [To increase its size, do the following as Administrator.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-clipboard/a49ed740-336a-4a1b-872c-90237503ac30)

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Pause</kbd> to open the *System* CPL.
- Select *Advanced system settings* for the *System Properties* dialog.
- Select the *Advanced* tab. [A bit redundant, *n'est-ce pas*?]
- Select *Performance* to view *Performance Options*.
- Select *Advanced* tab. [Yep, again.]
- Select *Virtual memory* to *Change* the page file size.
- Depending on available RAM and disk space, consider increasing the size. BTW, setting a *Custom size*, with *Initial size* and *Maximum size* set to the same value, prevents continual resizing of the page file, and concomitant disk fragmentation.

Second, there might be flaws in Microsoft's implementation of Windows History. [You can turn it off](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-use-the-new-and-improved-windows-10-clipboard), and try an alternative such as [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) or one of the other many [clipboard managers](https://beebom.com/best-paste-alternative-clipboard-managers-windows/). As with *any* software, check it at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) for possible malware.

And here's a workaround, though not an answer:

Add a [system sound for the Windows SnapShot](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/38022-add-remove-snapshot-sound-printscreen-key-windows.html) command, to confirm that screen shot was taken. You can do so using the tenforums.com .reg file, or follow these directions.

[image: Registr, adding SnapShot sound]

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>, type `reg` and select Regedit.
- Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\` (or copy and paste that into the Regedit location bar).
- Add a key for `SnapShot`.
- Add the key `.Current` to `SnapShot. Note leading end-stop (period).
- Add the key `.Default` to `SnapShot. Note leading end-stop (period).

Now you can either put the location of the sound file in the `(Default)` REG_SZ value, or use the Windows System Sounds control panel to select the sound for SnapShot.

Every time you press <kbd>Prtsc</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Prtsc</kbd> (and <kbd>Fn</kbd>, if needed), you should hear a confirmatory sound.

Why MS did not include that key is a puzzle...

Comment: What would you suggest I do if I don't hear the sound?  Once if fails, even I try again, it rarely starts working again.  If I get frustrated and find a different way to copy-paste, it may mysteriously start working again in 5 min to 20 min.

Comment: @user3533030, See changes to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try an uninstall and reinstall of the videocard drivers. Also use updated drivers.
AMD videocards are sometimes glitchy.